# How does meteorjs have string names as functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

Check out the following code snippet

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-task'(event) {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get value from form element
    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.text.value;

    // Insert a task into the collection
    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(), // current time
    });

    // Clear form
    target.text.value = '';
  },
});
```

This code snippet was taken from a tutorial on MeteorJS.

Notice `'submit .new-task'(event)`.  How is this possible? How would I go about doing the same without meteor?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 3):

It's a shortcut for:

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-task': function (event) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Meteor doesn't have anything to do with it.

Reference: http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties

Answer (score 0):

Events is an object of EventHandlers that are parsed by the following logic:

`'submit .new-task'` is interpreted as `onSubmit` for the selector `.new-task` and the declared function for this string is the function to be executed.

A jQuery equivalent would be:

```
$( ".new-task" ).on( "submit", (event) {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get value from form element
    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.text.value;

    // Insert a task into the collection
    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(), // current time
    });

    // Clear form
    target.text.value = '';
  },
});
```

Some main difference is, that in Blaze Template events, the current Template instance is passed as second parameter (not included in your example) that allows you to get/set template variables using `ReactiveVar` or `RactiveDict`.

Writing your custom events using jQuery would miss all the features, that Blaze gives you with event maps.

Read more on event maps here: http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps

Read more on jQuery events here: https://api.jquery.com/on/